# Javascript to manipulate array of objects and create two set of arrays for data and link

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an object array like the following.

```
 [
  {
    "name": "car",
    "value": "",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "v8_engine",
        "value": "",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "cylinder-arrangement",
            "value": "",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "type",
                "value": "string",
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "name": "max-elements",
                "value": "8",
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "other-parts",
        "value": "",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "per-cylinder-parts",
            "value": "",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "piston-diameter",
                "value": "",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "name": "type",
                    "value": "uint32",
                    "children": []

                  },
                  {
                    "name": "range",
                    "value": "2000... 9000",
                    "children": []

                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "name": "valves",
                "value": "",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "name": "number",
                    "value": "",
                    "children": []
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "position",
                    "value": "",
                    "children": []
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to parse through each elements and their respective childrens and manipulate it to create two set of arrays

1. Node data array that contains:key which is index of that element and values as shown

nodeDataArray.push({ key:i,Data: a.yang_type + " " + a.name}) or nodeDataArray.push({ key:i,Data: a.name + " " + a.value})

2. Link Data array that contains the link (parent child relation ship)

   linkDataArray.push({ from: i, to: j });

where i is the index of parent and j is index of child

I have the following function that parses through the elements and pushes them fine in to node data array with index.

```
vm.tree.forEach(loop);// here vm.tree is the json data, passed dynamically
 var i=0;
                    function loop(a) {

                        if(a.yang_type!='' && a.name!=''){
                          nodeDataArray.push({ key:i,Data: a.yang_type + " " + a.name, group: -1 });
                            //console.log("Data:",a.yang_type);
                            linkDataArray.push({ from: i, to: i+1 });
                      }

                        if(a.name!='' && a.value!=''){
                            nodeDataArray.push({ key:i,Data: a.name + " " + a.value, group: -1 });
                            linkDataArray.push({ from: 0, to: i+1 });

                        }

                        i=i+1;
                        // process you data
                        //if(Array.isArray(a.children)){j++;}
                        if(Array.isArray(a.children)){

                            //var g=0;
                            a.children.forEach(loop);
                        }


                    }
```

Below wordings is based on the sample JSON to make it more clear on what is my expected output should be

1. parse through the JSON and list out all the elements in the JSON object as shown below

   ```
   car
   v8_engine
   cylinder-arrangement
   type string 
   max-elements 8
   other_parts
   per-cylinder-parts
   piston-diameter
   type UINT32
   range 2000...3000
   valves
   number
   position
   ```
2. Then list of relationship based on parent and child index. Where car is the 0th element,v8_engine is the 2nd and so on … until the last one which is  position  being 12th

So we have total of 13 elements from the above example. Now I need to list their relation ship too. Like

```
0th element is parent of 1 and 5.
1st element is parent of 2
2nd element is parent of 3 and 4
and so on
```

Comment: Your code does not do what you want ?

Comment: it does the first part saving node data array but link data array doesnt map the correct parent and child based on JSON

Comment: This is not JSON, and has nothing to do with JSON. Please educate yourself on what JSON is (see json.org), and rewrite your question. Also, manipulating objects is not "parsing" them. The word "parsing" has a specific meaning, which is "the process of analyzing a string of symbols in accordance with a grammar". Also, please give a smaller, sample data set, and fix your over-indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate the parent list, you could use a closure with a `from` variable, which holds the node number from where it has been called.

BTW, your list above is not correct for `5th element is parent of 6 and 10`.

```js
function loop(from) {   
    return function (a) {
        var f = i;
        if (from !== undefined) {
            linkDataArray.push({ from: from, to: i });
        }
        i++;
        if (Array.isArray(a.children)) {
            a.children.forEach(loop(f));
        }
    };
}

var data = [{ "name": "car", "value": "", "children": [{ "name": "v8_engine", "value": "", "children": [{ "name": "cylinder-arrangement", "value": "", "children": [{ "name": "type", "value": "string", "children": [] }, { "name": "max-elements", "value": "8", "children": [] }] }] }, { "name": "other-parts", "value": "", "children": [{ "name": "per-cylinder-parts", "value": "", "children": [{ "name": "piston-diameter", "value": "", "children": [{ "name": "type", "value": "uint32", "children": [] }, { "name": "range", "value": "2000... 9000", "children": [] }] }, { "name": "valves", "value": "", "children": [{ "name": "number", "value": "", "children": [] }, { "name": "position", "value": "", "children": [] }] }] }] }] }],
    i = 0,
    linkDataArray = [];

data.forEach(loop());

console.log(linkDataArray);
```

Comment: I see you like the `a && do_something` idiom, but normal people write `if` statements. `&&` has the semantics of logical and. In addition, many if not most linters will choke on this syntax.

Comment: right, i like the short syntax. is it better now?

Comment: Thanks for accommodating a grumpy old guy.

Comment: @torazaburo.. Thank u sir !!!

Answer (score 0):

```
                    var i=0;
                    var nodeDataArray = [];
                    var linkDataArray = [];

                    function loop(from) {           
                        return function (a) {
                            var f = i;

                            if(a.yang_type!='' && a.name!=''){
                                  nodeDataArray.push({ key:i,Data: a.yang_type + " " + a.name, group: -1 });
                                  //c=c+a.name;
                                  //console.log("c:",c);
                                //console.log("Data:",a.yang_type);
                                //linkDataArray.push({ from: i, to: i+1 });
                              }

                            if(a.name!='' && a.value!=''){
                                nodeDataArray.push({ key:i,Data: a.name + " " + a.value, group: -1 });
                                //c=c+a.name+a.value;
                                console.log("c:",c);
                                //linkDataArray.push({ from: 0, to: i+1 });

                            }
                            if (from !== undefined) {
                                linkDataArray.push({ from: from, to: i });
                            }
                            i++;
                            if (Array.isArray(a.children)) {
                                a.children.forEach(loop(f));
                            }
                            //console.log("c:",c);
                        };

                    }
var data = [{ "name": "car", "value": "", "children": [{ "name": "v8_engine", "value": "", "children": [{ "name": "cylinder-arrangement", "value": "", "children": [{ "name": "type", "value": "string", "children": [] }, { "name": "max-elements", "value": "8", "children": [] }] }] }, { "name": "other-parts", "value": "", "children": [{ "name": "per-cylinder-parts", "value": "", "children": [{ "name": "piston-diameter", "value": "", "children": [{ "name": "type", "value": "uint32", "children": [] }, { "name": "range", "value": "2000... 9000", "children": [] }] }, { "name": "valves", "value": "", "children": [{ "name": "number", "value": "", "children": [] }, { "name": "position", "value": "", "children": [] }] }] }] }] }]
data.forEach(loop());
```